# Looking for information on modifying Boots Industries 3D printers

Tags: delta, belt

About two years ago I purchased a [Boots Industries](https://bootsindustries.com/) v.2.5 3D printer in a delta configuration. The wiki is still up at [this location](http://wiki.bootsindustries.com/wiki/Getting_started_with_the_BI_V2.5) where you can see what the printer looked like.

The printer is prone to break and slip because the design uses thin wire to move the carriages up and down. I'd like to convert my printer over to using a belt like the one on [this page](http://wiki.bootsindustries.com/wiki/Belt_conversion_instruction), but the conversion kit is no longer available. I believe I can 3D print the carriages, but would anyone be able to point me toward the resources to convert my printer over to using a toothed belt?

Comment: Did you already modify your printer? If so, could you share how you did it in an answer? If not, I'd try to write an answer to your question. In any case, the last two links are dead, please update them!

Comment: Yeah, in the time since I wrote my question the company has taken down their wiki. I don't know that they moved it anywhere though there's still a forum at http://forum.bootsindustries.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Contact Brian or Lykle.  We all have Boots Industries printers and have heavily modified it to belt drive and magnetic effectors.  The print quality has improved drastically.  The old Boots support group has since moved on to Slack and we are in constant contact everyday.

https://biv25.slack.com/messages/@slackbot/

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1843195

Comment: This isn't a very good answer, because it consists of solely external references. On StackExchange, answers are expected to stand on their own. While including external reference material is great, it can change or become unavailable rendering a link-only answer helpful. Please make sure your answer can be read independently of outside sources. Perhaps you could explain how the conversion is done, what parts are needed, how you need to change the firmware, etc...